# Custom animation between UIViewControllers using transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I am trying to use `UIViewController`'s transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration method but with a custom animation.

I have the following two view controllers added as children to a custom container UIViewController:

1. firstController - This is an instance of UITabBarController
2. secondController - This is a subclass of UIViewController

The following code works as expected:

```
[self transitionFromViewController:firstController
                  toViewController:secondController 
                          duration:2                                         
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft  
                        animations:^(void){} 
                        completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

However I would like to create a custom animation where the where `firstController` slides to the left and is replaced by `secondController` sliding in from the right similar to how UINavigationControllers push and pop methods work.  After changing the `options` to `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone` I have tried to implement custom animations in the `animations` block but have had absolutely no success.  `firstController` is immediately swapped for `secondController` without and animations.

I would really appreciate any help.

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is actually really easy.  For some reason I assumed that the `secondController`'s view  would be be under/ behind that of `firstController`'s.  I had only tried to animate the `firstController`'s view.  This of course is wrong. As soon as `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration` is called `secondController`'s view is placed over `firstController`'s view.  The following code works:

```
CGFloat width = self.view.frame.size.width;
CGFloat height = self.view.frame.size.height;

secondController.view.frame = CGRectMake(width, 0, width, height);

[self transitionFromViewController:firstController
    toViewController:secondController
    duration:0.4
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
    animations:^(void) {
        firstController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0 - width, 0, width, height);
        secondController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    } 
    completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [secondController didMoveToParentViewController:self]; 
    }
];
```

Comment: You should call [secondController didMoveToParentViewController:self]; in the completion handler too :)

Comment: @banDedo I updated the code with that.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Needed that!